# Inverting a function in the positive reals

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

So I am trying to take the inverse of a function which I will then differentiate. I am only interested in solutions in the positive real domain. There is a subproblem here which is how to treat exponents as some examples:

If I put in `x^2 = u`, I want it to give me `u^(1/2)`.

If I give it the `u=logx`, I want it to give me the exponential of `u`. Etc, etc,

Is there a simple way to do this? The problem is that it returns too many solutions, is there a way to just drop the negative solutions?

```
from sympy import *
x, b, a, u, t, dt, dW = symbols('x b a u t dt dW', real = True)
utility = Eq(x**2, u)
invutility = solveset(utility, x)
```

Which gives:

```
{-sqrt(u), sqrt(u)}
```

I am only interested in the positive solution.

Comment: at least for the square root you can filter the solution by hand

Comment: Do you want it to output the equation or the numerical value? There is no easy way to do this but if you want the numerical value someone did make a [library for it](https://pypi.org/project/pynverse/).

Comment: You probably need [invert_real](https://www.asmeurer.com/sympy_doc/dev/_modules/sympy/solvers/solveset.html)

Comment: I want a general solution, not just for the square root. Invert_real, how does that work?

Comment: Did you try `solveset(utilities, x, domain=S.Reals)`?

Comment: @smichr yes(just now). It gives me an error. Looks to be internal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`solve` will give you these solutions if you declare the variables as positive:

```
>>> x, u = var('x u',positive=True)
>>> utility = Eq(x**2, u)
>>> solve(utility,x)
[sqrt(u)]
>>> solve(u-log(x),x)
[exp(u)]
```